# python Dataframe filter column by column value and column name is user input

Tags: python

I have a dataframe data df

```
0   Easting Northing  domain grade
1   3900     4100      2    0.02
2   3910     4100      3    0.01
3   3910     4100      3    0.01
4   3910     4100      2    0.01
```

I can to create a new subset dataframe by filtering the column domain==3

```
tempdf=df[df.domain==3]
```

What I want is I want to use a variable to substitute column name like print '%s'%variable
   because sometimes I don't know the exact name. It might be Domain or Dom so I will give such mannually

```
custome_rawinput='domain'
```

`tempdf=df[df.'%s'%custome_rawinput==3]`

but this will give me an error(invalid syntax)

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subscript` on the dataframe to select the column by string, In your case -

```
tempdf=df[df['%s'%custome_rawinput]==3]
```

Though the `'%s'` in that is really unneccessary, you can directly use the below , since `custome_rawinput` is already string -

```
tempdf=df[df[custome_rawinput]==3]
```

Example/Demo -

```
In [4]: inp = 'A'

In [5]: df[df[inp] == 1]
Out[5]:
   A  B
0  1  2

In [6]: df[df[inp] == 2]
Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []

In [7]: df[df[inp] == 3]
Out[7]:
   A  B
1  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` to access it with a label. [You can read more about this if you're interested](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label). Essentially, you just treat it like a normal python dictionary, so do:

```
rawinput='domain'
tempdf = df[ df[rawinput] == 3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @TomWong happy to help :). If your issue is fixed, please mark it as answered and pick whichever answer helped you. This is so future users with a similar problem can find this and use it as help